# Using adjustResize with fragments and requestFocus

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I'm trying to create an activity with a single `RelativeLayout` used as a fragment container, where each fragment has a separate background color that bleeds under a translucent status bar, and where the activity as a whole accounts for the keyboard size.

The layout for the activity is:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

The fragments are wrapped with:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:animateLayoutChanges="true" />
```

And the activity is defined as:

```
<activity android:screenOrientation="portrait"
          android:name=".login.LoginActivity"
          android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" />
```

Everything is working fine for the first fragment. The activity resizes the `RelativeLayout`, the fragment contained within it resizes to adjust for the keyboard, and everything is fine. However, when replacing one fragment with another that uses `<requestFocus />` on its `<EditText />`, the keyboard stays up but the second fragment that is pushed on takes the full screen size (under the keyboard). Closing and re-opening the keyboard causes the activity to re-measure and then everything is fine. Similarly, if the keyboard changes height during the fragment transition (when moving from a field that doesn't support autocorrection to one that does, so the keyboard gets taller), the fragment measures correctly. So it only appears to be a problem when transitioning between two fragments where the keyboard size is constant.

Adding `fitsSytemWindows=true` to the wrapping `RelativeLayout` fixes the problem, but also prevents the fragment's view from appearing under the status bar, which isn't what I want. Is there some way to force the fragment to re-measure or something that I'm missing? This is using native fragments, not app-compat.

Comment: Which theme you are using for this?

Comment: @AndyDeveloper I'm using `Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar` (with `colorPrimaryDark` set to a translucent black for the status bar)

Comment: Try this Theme:: @android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar
and android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|stateAlwaysHidden"

Comment: No dice with those options. I don't think the theme is the issue, though. The activity does adjust, for the keyboard state, but when future fragments are added to the container they simply measure at the wrong size (initially)